# How to setup OAuth2, LDAP authentication for different endpoints in Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-security-ldap

In my application I have some REST layer that requires valid OAuth2 access_token to be invoked. Also I have WebDav endpoint that must require authentication via LDAP. My current Spring Resource Server configuration is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
public class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    private final ResourceServerProperties resource;
    private final OAuth2AuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint;

    @Value("${security.oauth2.server.public.paths}")
    private String[] publicPaths;

    @Autowired
    public ResourceServerConfiguration(ResourceServerProperties resource, UnauthorizedEntryPoint unauthorizedEntryPoint) {
        this.resource = resource;
        this.unauthorizedEntryPoint = unauthorizedEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // Logout functionality is implemented in LogoutController.
        http.logout().disable();

        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(publicPaths).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/api/secure/password/**").hasAnyAuthority(USER_ROLES)
            .antMatchers("/webdav/**").authenticated()

            .antMatchers("/**").denyAll();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedEntryPoint).resourceId(this.resource.getResourceId());
    }
}
```

Global Security Configuration:

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected MethodSecurityExpressionHandler createExpressionHandler() {
        return new OAuth2MethodSecurityExpressionHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(MyCustomOAuth2AuthenticationProvider myCustomOAuth2AuthenticationProvider, ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider) {
        return new ProviderManager(Arrays.asList(myCustomOAuth2AuthenticationProvider, activeDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider));
    }
}
```

When I open `/webdav/something` URL via browser I retrieve default OAuth2 401 error message "Full authentication is required to access this resource".

How to configure Spring to try invoke `ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider` instead of showing the default error message?